# Convert this statement to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ. Is it possible to convert this statement into LINQ statement?

```
        var jobs = (from a in auditData.AsEnumerable()
                    join b in _dbContext.Jobs.AsEnumerable() on a.JobId equals b.Id.ToString()
                    select new { a, b.JobId }).ToList(); 

        foreach (var job in jobs) {
            foreach (var audit in auditData)
            {
                if(job.a.Id == audit.Id)
                {
                    audit.JobId = job.JobId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I believe that there is a way to convert this one into a LINQ statement.  But I just don't know how. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: So which statement is "this statement" that you want to convert into LINQ?

Comment: 1. LINQ does not bond very well with data modification , so I would say usually iteration approach is better. 2. why do you need `AsEnumerable` in your LINQ query? 3. If this is code for EF Framework - there is no build in functionality to create queries like `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...` so you probably will need to look into 3rd party libraries like [EntityFramework Extensions](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions) or [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this because during my earlier days I had the same question on how we could potentially use LINQ to do things within the pipeline. The following might not work as it is because of how little information I have to go on but it should have enough information for you to be able to make this work on your own:

```cs
//Run an IN query on SQL end and get jobs that match our auditData JobIds
var firstUpdatedJob = _dbContext.Jobs.Where(job => auditData.Select(audit => audit.JobId).Contains(job.Id.ToString()))
    //Get all the Job Ids that matched - there's no need to get audit back because this matches 100% on auditData
    .Select(job => job.Id)
    //Switch from EF to Linq2Objects
    .AsEnumerable()
    //Inner join on Audit Data and we'll have all the jobs we care about with a match in DB
    .Join(auditData, jobId => jobId, audit => audit.Id, (jobId, audit) => {
        //This is what you were doing in foreach when you matched
        audit.JobId = jobId;
        //we must return a result. I'm choosing to return audit
        return audit;
    })
    //VERY IMPORTANT: LINQ is Lazy. None of the above will execute unless you force it somehow.
    //Coincidentally because of your break, FirstOrDefault will be equivalent which also forces execution
    //And will cause the side effect to take place
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The above is a single statement built as a transformation pipeline. If you actually want to process all auditData, you should remove `FirstOrDefault()` and instead use something that forces full collection evaluation. `Count()` is an option if you just want to force evaluation without needing the collection itself. Alternatively you can use `ToArray()` instead if you do want the transformed edit to come back.

Given that your `auditData` is getting modified through side effect, you don't need to create another copy of collection and you can just use `auditData` as it is for next steps with updated `JobId`.

Comment: To the person doing drive-by negative vote - please actually share constructive feedback if you know better. Blindly giving negative votes only harms the community and surely you don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is a technology. On top of that are implemented EF, EF Core, linq2db, LinqToSQL, etc.

**Assuming that you are using EF Core**

You cannot do that effectively with EF Core. You have to load records into memory and update them as you did in question.

But there are extensions for EF Core which can improve such task. For example [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

```cs
var auditToUpdate = 
    from a in auditData
    join b in _dbContext.Jobs on Convert.ToInt32(a.JobId) equals b.Id
    select new { a, b }; 

auditToUpdate
    .Set(u => u.a.JobId, u => u.b.JobId)
    .Update();
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** I saw other contributors' answers on this question, and they are much better than mine, but, if You have the time for that, You can read it as an interesting addition.

LINQ helps you to construct IEnumerbles from existing ones, not to change existing ones (for that purpose loops are perfect).
It achieves that by providing basic rules that you can combine. For example:

```
var l = new List<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2 });
var e = from item in l where item > 0 select item;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", e));

l.Add(3);
Console.WriteLine("Added value: 3");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", e));
```

This will produce the following output:

```
1, 2
Added value: 3
1, 2, 3
```

Let us see it line by line:

1. We create a list with the elements 0, 1, 2
2. We create an IEnumerable with the *RULE*: "select all items from list l, which is greater than 0"
3. We check the content of the created IEnumerable: 1, 2
4. We add the value 3
5. We check the content again, and see that the IEnumerable updated. BUT WHY?

Because the IEnumerable stores the *RULE*, so when we construct the string from it to output its values, we in fact say, that "select all items from list l, which is greater than 0"

So LINQ is basically for this: to construct new IEnumerables from existing one by telling a rule, based on which we can update it every time we query its items.

**Note**: if you want to store an IEnumerable in its current state, just call:

```
e.ToArray();
```

This will create a *new* array with the current values of e, which depends no more on the changes to list l.
An example:

```
var l = new List<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2 });
var e = from item in l where item > 0 select item;
var a = e.ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", e));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a));

l.Add(3);
Console.WriteLine("Added value: 3");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", e));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a));
```

And the output:

```
1, 2
1, 2
Added value: 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2
```

I hope this will help You. If not, just note, that your code is correct, You do not need to modify it, and, of course questions are welcome.

Comment: Just wanted to say Welcome to the community. It can be daunting to add your first reply and I can see you've put effort in your answer even if it isn't the direct answer. Your answer's -1 is most likely because of that reason (sadly that person hasn't left feedback). Generally speaking you only offer a direct answer to the question being asked and avoid conceptual discussion in an answer (you can invite them into a chat once you have some more rep for details)

Comment: Thanks! I actually wouldn't have noticed I got -1, if You don't write this comment :). I'm still really thankful though, because I know I've got to be a part of a supporting community. I will pay attention for your advice.